# Making one project a sub-project of another project in coq?

Tags: dependencies, coq

I am [testing a coq project called corn](https://github.com/c-corn/corn), which requires another project `MathClasses` as a dependency. I was able to compile the dependency project `MathClasses` via a `sudo make install` kind-of process.

However, there are certain features in the `make install` process that I don't like.

Firstly, if I do a `make` again, coq seem to be confused about what's already installed somewhere in the system and what's currently being compiled.

Secondly, the project did not provide a `remove` or `uninstall` method in the `make` file. And I suspect this might cause me problems when I upgrade to a new version of `coq`.

So my questions are:

1. Is it possible (and how) to make the dependency project (i.e. `MathClasses`) a sub-project of `CoRN`, so that I can compile the whole thing by issuing one command from the top project (`CoRN`)?
2. After I `make` a `coq` project, can I load it into `coqtop` without `install` it into the system directories? (i.e. How can I modify and test the project locally).

Thanks in advance.

-- EDIT --

@Arthur Azevedo De Amorim : You mentioned

> Plus, OPAM makes it possible to work with your own local version of a package

Any further pointers about this?

Thanks again

Comment: Just added a link to the OPAM documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Setting up sub-projects

You can always set up the load path in the project `Makefile`, so that it finds exactly the version of the library you want.

Suppose that your copy MathClasses lives in `/path/to/MathClasses`. You can then add the following line to the `Make.in` file in the CoRN distribution:

```
-R path/to/MathClasses/ MathClasses
```

After doing that, the compilation process should be able to find the MathClasses files.

That being said, installing a package directly is not such a big deal. I find it strange that Coq is getting confused about which files to use when you hit `make`; could you include which error messages you are getting? While upgrading Coq by yourself can cause problems with the libraries that are already installed, removing the problematic files is just a matter of removing the corresponding directory (`MathClasses`, in your case) under the `user-contribs` directory of your Coq library path.

Also, managing your Coq install is probably easier with [OPAM](https://opam.ocaml.org/). There is a [GitHub repository](https://github.com/coq/repo-stable) with updated Coq packages that can be used with OPAM, including MathClasses and CoRN; using it would make the whole Coq update problem go away. Plus, OPAM makes it possible to work with your own local version of a package (see [here](https://opam.ocaml.org/doc/Packaging.html#Opampin)), which seems what you want to do with CoRN.

## Loading packages

If you are using Emacs and Proof General, you can configure a project's load path directly, as explained [here](http://proofgeneral.inf.ed.ac.uk/htmlshow.php?title=Proof%20General%20user%20manual%20%28latest%20release%29&file=releases%2FProofGeneral-latest%2Fdoc%2FProofGeneral%2FProofGeneral_10.html#Using-file-variables).